# How to connect OS X Yosemite to a Windows based SSTP VPN?

Tags: macos, network, wifi, windows, vpn

I am trying to connect to a Windows based SSTP VPN network. I am using OS X Yosemite, I was wondering if there is any solution that can allow me to connect to a SSTP based VPN.

For the record, I have already tried using EasyVPN, iSSTP, iSSTP2. all of which failed to connect, and they all seem to be not supported anymore.

Comment: anyone have any clues?

Answer (score 5):

The [sstp-client](http://sstp-client.sourceforge.net/) works for me. It is a command-line program. I installed it using the homebrew command:

```
brew install sstp-client
```

Comment: Hi Jose,  I have installed sstp-client using brew on my mac. However, there are no tutorials on how to use it on mac os x though, they only have tutorials  for linux as it seems. How do you run it in Mac os x?

Comment: @Yury has posted [below](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/264507/7663) on how to run it in Mac OS X.

Answer (score 3):

Please check my answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40590806/windows-sstp-vpn-connect-from-mac/40590807#40590807

There I explained how I connect Mac to Windows SSTP (probably threads should be merged)

Comment: That link is very helpful. Combined with the company data on services - it seemed to work first time.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is [iSSTP - a SSTP client for Mac OS X](https://www.axot.org/2015/03/03/isstp-a-sstp-client-for-mac-osx/).

> This is a sstp GUI client for Mac, use a modified sstp-client as backend which support server-name TLS extension. Some servers(ex: *.vpnazure.net) require server-name, otherwise the sstp connection will be rejected.

The reason for being the best bet is that this is the only one (to my knowledge) SSTP client for Mac up to now.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide info as to why they're the best. Explain why you think the link you provided will answer the question.  Links can change and become outdated so we prefer the answers to not just be a link.  See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer. - From Review

Comment: I am also use iSSTP as an UI for for sstp-client - the only one free application I found.

Answer (score 0):

As others pointed out the best way would be to install sstp-client but iSSTP can also work, however note the following:

1. You need to ensure you get the latest version (**1.0.15** currently) as 1.0.14 has a bug and does not work.
2. If you use **iSSTP** ensure you replace their bundled sstpc file (Contents/Resources) with the latest from where you installed it (/usr/local/Cellar/sstp-client/1.0.15/sbin)

So,

Install with `brew install sstp-client`

Run:

```
sudo /usr/local/Cellar/sstp-client/1.0.15/sbin/sstpc --password *** --user *** <host>
```

For PAP I use the following command:

```
sudo /usr/local/Cellar/sstp-client/1.0.15/sbin/sstpc --password *** --user *** <host> noauth defaultroute require-pap
```

In iSSTP (once you replace their old binary) ensure you set the pptp options in advanced (see here: https://linux.die.net/man/8/pppd)

Answer (score -1):

I think you will find [Tunnelblick](https://tunnelblick.net/%20%22Tunnelblick) will do it without any problems. It's well supported and has good documentation on the site.

Comment: Tunnelblick does not support SSTP.

Comment: Tunnelblick is for OpenVPN as I know