# SSTP VPN client for Mac OS that supports EAP-MSCHAP-v2

Tags: network, security, vpn

There are already a few questions here about VPN clients that work on Mac OS which support SSTP:

- [How to connect OS X Yosemite to a Windows based SSTP VPN?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/247244/how-to-connect-os-x-yosemite-to-a-windows-based-sstp-vpn)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40590806/windows-sstp-vpn-connect-from-mac/40590807

Unfortunately, we have tried those solutions and they do not work for us. The reason is because they only work with insecure authentication mechanisms. In particular, they seem to rely on support for the insecure and obsolete **mschap-v2** protocol. This is literally referred to as a "Less secure authentication method" these days, and as we are a financial institution, I have no desire to enable that. Hence the question: SSTP VPN client for Mac OS ***that supports EAP-MSCHAP-v2***.

Our VPN setup works perfectly on Windows, but as usual, there seem to be compatability issues with Mac OS. sstp-client seems to require MSCHAP-V2. We tested by temporarily allowing MSCHAP-V2 to our VPN server and through Network Access Protocol, and... it worked! So, these clients **do** work, but only with less secure authentication methods, and not with more secure authentication methods.

I've tried looking for ways to configure these to use EAP-MSCHAPV2, which is what Windows clients are using, and we've tried manually testing that, but so far everything has failed. I'm puzzled how such a basic security option could be missing here. How might these clients be used/modified to work without enabling MSCHAP-V2 support? Or, is there another client that actually supports secure connections?

For other reasons, we would like to continue using the SSTP protocol, so changing protocols is not an option. We don't need more than 128 connections. The **only** issue is Mac OS. Everything else is perfect for us, so I'm hoping there's a way around this? I don't use Mac OS, so I'm hoping some Mac guru who may have encountered the same problem knows of a workaround.

Comment: Any luck on this?

Comment: @vr_driver We ended up setting up a L2TP VPN just for the Macs (I know). It's prone to issues and never works as well as SSTP, but I don't use Macs, so I don't worry about it too much.

Comment: Thanks for the Tip. We've just come from this, and have strangely gone to MSCHAPV2, I think so they can have 2FA?