# Using Windows Connection Manager based VPN on macOS

Tags: network, vpn

IT department of my company sent me a zip file for connecting to our corporate VPN. I understand that it is a deployable Windows VPN client called “Connection Manager” and it was prepared with Windows Connection Manager Administration Kit. It seems that is supposed to be installed on Windows without any parameter. After installing I have just entered my username and password and since then I can establish a VPN connection on Windows 10 without any problem.

The main question is: How can I connect to that same VPN service from my Mac. I primarily use my Mac and switching to Windows PC every time when I need corporate resources is a pain in the neck.

I find out that it is an SSTP VPN connection. I also can see the VPN server address from connection properties. There are files in the installation package named "routing.txt", "vpn.cms", "vpn.inf" and "cmroute.dll". I can see lots of parameters in these except "cmroute.dll" but do not know what to do with them.

Is there any chance for me to connect to my corporate VPN on macOS Catalina? How can I use the parameters from the installation package on macOS? (IT department is not helping me. They suggest using Windows. :) So getting help from them is out of the question)

Comment: Please don't cross-post to multiple SE sites. Pick one & stick to it. https://superuser.com/questions/1608779/using-windows-connection-manager-based-vpn-on-macos

Comment: It is not clear that you are _required_ to use a Mac to do your job. Your IT department is being negligent and obstructive by not supplying the software you need, or at least assisting you in figuring out what you can do, even if doing so is for your convenience only. If you are required to use a Mac, perhaps your employer, (who hires and fires IT,) should know you're being prevented from doing your work in a timely and secure manner. Where I work, such negligent obstruction is grounds for disciplinary action.

Comment: I think your IT department is probably going to be your best chance of success. Stock macOS supports a few VPN types and OpenVPN can be used by installing tunnelblick.

Answer (score 1):

It seems a similar question (connecting to SSTP VPN) is answered here:
[How to connect OS X Yosemite to a Windows based SSTP VPN?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/247244/how-to-connect-os-x-yosemite-to-a-windows-based-sstp-vpn/264507#264507)

and here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40590806/windows-sstp-vpn-connect-from-mac/40590807#40590807

Especially on the last one, ppl seem to have succeeded in connecting.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have downloaded the app mentioned in the first link. But what about the parameters?